# Can I set up one android phone, create a backup and restore it in multiple phones?

Tags: backup, restore, multiple-devices

Where I work, we give all salesmen an Android phone with a set of multiple preinstalled apps, a predefined contact list, some predefined settings and restricted permissions over the phone's configuration.

I am responsible for setting up all of these things before giving the phone to the user, and it is a very repetitive and long process (almost an hour). I am looking for a smart way for automating or shortening the process as the set-up is always the same except for certain account information:

1. Set up the brand new phone with a unique gmail account we create for each salesmen. (THIS IS ONE OF THE STEPS THAT REQUIRE A UNIQUE ACCOUNT FOR EACH PHONE).
2. Install all predefined apps.
3. Set up all predefined apps.
4. Restrict permissions (using an app).

I'm thinking that a viable way of doing this is to completely set up one phone manually and do a complete backup of the phone to a computer. Then, in the future the only thing that I would have to do is to "Restore" the brand new phone with the backup and change only the settings that differ from user to user (i.e the phone's gmail account, the play store's account, the Whatsapp phone number, etc...)

Is this possible and viable?

How could I do this (which app could I use)?

The only caveat I can anticipate is that the original phone would be set up with a particular gmail account, phone number, etc..  Will I have any problem changing this setting in the restored phones?

Thanks !

Comment: The user wrote this much but didn't register! Anyway, you can find many backup solutions for unrooted phones here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices I prefer  complete `adb backup`.